# Function hide() , prev() , show() are assembled to get required result but unable to understand its working?

Tags: javascript

I have got a script which works fine. The script is :

```
var minimized_elements = $('.innovision-msg');
  var minimize_character_count = 100;    
  minimized_elements.each(function(){    
    var t = $(this).text();        
    if(t.length < minimize_character_count ) return;
    $(this).html(
      t.slice(0,minimize_character_count)+
      '<span>...</span>'+'<a href="#" class="read_more" style="color:#1a51c6;">Read more</a>'+
      '<span style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(minimize_character_count ,t.length)+ '<span>...</span>' +
     '<a href="#" class="read_less" style="color:#1a51c6;">Read less</a></span>'
    );  
  });
  $('a.read_more', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide().prev().hide();
    $(this).next().show();        
  });
  $('a.read_less', minimized_elements).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();    
  });
```

Here in this script i can not understand the meaning and use of code:

```
$(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();
```

Can any one explains what this line of code means ?

Moreover when it set var minimize_character_count = 250; Script does not works.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of each of those functions? Do you understand them? What do you not understand in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically `chaining` which works on an returned object

```
$(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();
```

`$(this)` referring to either `'a.read_less', minimized_elements`

On click on this element , it will find the `parent` dom and will `hide` it.

`.prev()` is use to select the previous element. So it will select the previous element and will show it. Again using `prev()` will select previous to previous element and will also show it

Comment: But when it var minimize_character_count = 250; script does not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();
```

This line is hiding the `parent` element of `this` element which is clicked (for minimization). After hiding the parent element, it goes to the `previous sibling` (of the `parent` element) and make it `visible`. It again goes to the `previous sibling` (of the previous sibling of the parent element) and make it visible.

Basically, jquery methods (after doing their job, whether to hide, show or traverse) returns the reference to the current element which allows you to chain the methods in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Method chaining is one of the nice features of jQuery. Most of the methods will return objects on which it is called, and hence you can call other methods in same chain.

> Yet another one of the really cool aspects of jQuery is the fact that
>   most of the methods returns a jQuery object that you can then use to
>   call another method. This allows you to do command chaining, where you
>   can perform multiple methods on the same set of elements, which is
>   really neat because it saves you and the browser from having to find
>   the same elements more than once - [source](http://www.jquery-tutorial.net/introduction/method-chaining/)